# ValidatePattern in PowerShell - Intelligent Piping

Tags: c#, powershell

Imagine this CmdLet:

```
Request-RemoteAssistance [-IPAddress <string>]
Request-RemoteAssistance [-HostName <string>]
```

Where both parameters could take data from the pipeline. Both parameters are strings, so type resolution isn't going to work. If the IP address had a regex validation attribute applied, if a non-IP-address-formatted string came in, would PS automatically see that its not valid for IPAddress and pipe it into the HostName parameter instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, powershell can't resolve parametersets by a regex.  I agree that would be cool, but it's not possible in v3.

You options are

- Put those 2 parameters in different parametersets, which each have other unique parameters, so the resolution is done by which other parameters are present
- Don't validate the format on either, do additional processing in your cmdlet body
- Provide only a single parameter, perhaps `-Host`, which accepts either an IP or a hostname.  Use `switch -regex` internally to pick if it's a hostname or an IP, then process accordingly.

If you can't do #1, I would recommend #3.  Unless you need other special parameters for each case, it's easiest for the user if they can use an IP or a hostname in a single place.  Most other tools would allow the same.